# Обработка строк по условию

Tags: python, строки, list

Прочитайте с клавиатуры список строк, разделенных пробелами. Для каждой строки списка:
если ее длина строго больше 3-х, приведите строку к нижнему регистру,
если длина нечетная, то первый символ сделайте заглавным.
Начал с этого:

```
inp = input()
L = inp.split('*')
if len(L)>3: print(lower(L))
```

Comment: `Прочитайте с клавиатуры список строк, разделенных пробелами` - строка подразумевает совокупность слов, разделённых пробелами или знаками препинания, а что такое строки разделённые пробелами?

Answer (score -1):

```
list = input().split()
for i in range(len(list)):
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: слова "больше 3" в условии предполагают, что где-то в коде должно быть число 3. В этом коде его нет, значит задачу он не решает хотя бы уже по этой причине. Минус.